Get Data into Datatable from power bi public URL in C#
Is there a way to get Data from a power bi Public url into a Datatable in C#?
Url is= https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiODUxZTU4ZjAtYmMyYi00NmRkLWIxZGYtNGIzODU1NTkzN2IxIiwidCI6ImFlNjg1NjQ3LWIyZmEtNGI3Yy1iZjU2LTg1ZTQyZDJmNjQzOCIsImMiOjR9
I want to get that Data on a DataTable

What data? There's no data at the url: just a chart, which is a visualization over data.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938785/power-bi-rest-api-export-to-excel-current-selection-using-c-sharp

@JoelCoehoorn Hi, I wantg to get data Data on that chart as a table.
